# 90s TV show: Nazi hunter time travels to the past to gather evidence and sue Nazis

Tags: story-identification, tv

There was an episode of a tv show I saw back in the mid 90s.

It took place modern day (mid 90s). It was about a Jewish man who was a Nazi hunter. He had brought several former Nazis to justice still hiding with assumed names.

It was revealed that he got his evidence by traveling back in time to the Nazi era, collecting evidence, and bringing it back to the future with him to use at their trials.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly season 5 episode 12 of *The Outer Limits* titled "[Tribunal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0667995/?ref_=ttep_ep12)"

> Aaron Zgierski, a lawyer and the son of Holocaust survivors, is investigating the Nazi war criminal who murdered members of his family. He gets help from a mysterious time traveler who is able to procure evidence from Auschwitz in 1944.

Aired in 1999 so not exact and the plot is not 100% but close enough to at least suggest.

Comment: You beat me by six minutes, had to let the dog out.  Here's a clip to help the OP decide.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTFIpQEDxEc&list=PLkqk0w_v4Zp69MJ3p8gOhJIO8ERytkZdh&index=37&t=0s